# Ajax refreshing for questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, ajax

Can Stack Overflow implement AJAX refreshing for questions and answers (the way it works on Gmail, or similar to Slashdot's 'New Stories' feature)?

Comment: whew, I'm glad that I was able to edit this. I tried to edit it on SO before the move was made, but it was migrated a second before I could hit 'enter'.

Comment: Technically, you do get a "new answer posted" message if you are on the question and a new answer is submitted.

Answer (score 7):

It wouldn't work while you were answering a question - as the text box would potentially move out from under your cursor while you were typing. Not a good thing.

While answering you get the notification of new answers at the top and have the option of reloading the page - I think that's enough.

There might be a benefit to extending this to occur while just reading answers, but again I wouldn't want it to happen automatically.

I can't see any use for it on the questions page though.

Comment: Cool factor? I agree with you, but an endless stream of questions showing appearing and flashing through your eyes in all its AJAXy glory would be... cool.

Comment: *I'm not endorsing gold plating only for being cool.*

Comment: I'd love to see the alert on a question page regardless of whether or not you're answering. Chances are that if you're looking at the page you'd like to know if there's a new answer and you need to refresh.