# Stop votes being applied to posts that aren't the most recent version

Tags: feature-request, notifications, voting

Currently you can look at a page and decide to vote (up or down) based on what you see. If that's been sitting on your screen for awhile it may have vastly changed. If the post (question or answer) you're trying to vote on has changed then it should bring back an error saying "Post has changed, please refresh" or simply refresh it automatically.

Occasionally I've seen downvotes (with comments) given for errors in posts that I'd corrected 15 minutes earlier.

Voting involves a server call so this would not be adding any server roundtrips.

Comment: Related question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/ajax-refreshing-for-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 10):

On the one hand, I like the idea of being notified if what i'm voting on doesn't match what's actually there.

On the other hand, the voting UI has become *all too annoying* lately, with the complex rules surrounding when votes can be reverted or reversed leading to frequent run-ins with the dreaded "Vote too old to be changed" error. Indeed, it is **single handedly turning my love of jQuery-faded `div`s into a *deep and abiding* hatred** for all things boxy and fade...y. I really don't care to see any more *errors* when i'm just trying to vote.

Updating it automatically though... yeah, now *that* I could handle. If code is to be added to detect this scenario server-side, i'd much prefer that it send back **the actual updated post**. The client script can then display it, and i can immediately revert my vote if need be. It could even use that little fading highlight effect normally reserved for pointing out an author's own just-posted answer; i still kinda like that one.

Comment: "I really don't care to see any more errors when i'm just trying to vote." you guys are doing some really wacky voting, then. I've undone a vote maybe 4-5 times, ever.

Comment: I drink a lot of coffee and enjoy clicking things, *ok*?

Answer (score 1):

If we had more facebook-style ajax updating we wouldn't have this problem. New answers or edits could appear as if by magic.

Answer (score 0):

Or possibly implement a version of the "new posts have been added while you're answering" script to do something like "n posts have been added or changed since you loaded the page."

Comment: See my answer to the related question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/ajax-refreshing-for-questions-and-answers/23489#23489