# Alert when answers are added to the question being viewed even when not entering an answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, alerts

This hasn't happened to me often yet, so I could be completely wrong about the current behaviour :)

Having just started to answer questions I find that I go off to research an answer, meanwhile <strike>Jon Skeet</strike> Tony the Pony jumps in and answers it. If I had started typing an answer I would see the alert immediately, but without typing I don't get an alert.

Also, if I were reading a question I wouldn't see the alert and may miss reading an answer.

It would be nice if the "new answer" alerts appeared regardless of what you were doing on a question page.

Comment: This has been mentioned before - will have to go searching for the link though

Comment: Found it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/ajax-refreshing-for-questions-and-answers/

Comment: Thanks - I searched but missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this, simply type a few characters in the answer box to trigger the dynamic "new answer added!" lookups.

Otherwise, every user on the page would trigger lookups to our servers, which is a) not sustainible, and b) 99.99% of them don't care because they aren't answering.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with this, for the same reasons. I'm usually off seeing if I can answer the question, and I have to remember to refresh the page before starting an answer so that I'm not duplicating answers and wasting my time.

I would love to see this feature implemented exactly how it is now when a user is adding/editing an answer.