# Live updating feed counter of new questions asked, similar to Facebook/Twitter

Tags: feature-request, questions, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto Loading of New Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/auto-loading-of-new-questions)

I know a social site is not a good example of reasoning, but what I'm referring to is how Facebook (or Twitter) has a live feed that populates automatically. Not asking to see user activity, but instead use this type of approach to populate new questions as they are asked.

For example, when answering a question, the orange display on SO that pops up saying

> 2 new answers loaded

which by clicking on them would load the answers without doing a complete page refresh.

Instead of you having to refresh the page yourself, a notification could popup (live running only under `newest` tab) saying something like:

> 3 new questions were asked

**OR** at least show the number of new questions embedded in the tab!

[sample http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/1227/change.png](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/1227/change.png)

Comment: Dupe of something, I think it was denied though. Also, I don't think that's a freehand circle.

Comment: -1 For Freehand circle, -1 for Facebook suggestion, +2 for image.

Comment: It's not a freehand circle. It's almost a freehand arrow, though. :)

Comment: @Cigars - I think that's what the -1 was for.

Comment: What happens when you have 673 new questions? Does it just reload the page, or does it try to load them all into the existing page and violently kill our browsers?