# Get alerted, so that I can answer questions in the fastest way

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions

I am interested in answering questions regarding C, C++, Linux, networking, etc.  I know that to increase in reputation the fastest way, it's very necessary to be the first at replying to the question.  How can I be alerted in the fastest way?

Comment: You could vote for this feature-request, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions, then you'd be able to setup all the tags you're interested in, and all the noisy questions that slow you down would be filtered out.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/auto-loading-of-new-questions

Comment: This solved the issue... Its a nice app build by akarnokd..
I also told him to add a feature of adding bitwise operations in searching feature & he was so quick.. 
http://code.google.com/p/open-so-frontend/

Answer (score 3):

It would be great if the questions list were dynamically updated every so often with JavaScript using the Comet technique, like how new status updates are shown on Facebook. It would save people from having to hit F5 every 5 seconds.

Comment: If there's such feature, it'll probably be an on-demand option. Esle it'll add considerable amount of redundant load to the servers too.

Comment: @o.k.w: why? If it's implemented properly (for example, an ever running **single** C++/C#/whatever fastcgi process) that pools the database every second, it will probably run just fine on my 412mhz iPhone. If it's done poorly (one process for every user online) then it requires several servers.

Comment: It doesn't even need to poll the database every second, every 10-15 seconds would be plenty. You could also detect when the user is idle, like Facebook does, and not run the code during that time.

Answer (score 1):

- Bookmark the tag(s)
- Make sure view sort is "Newest"
- Hit F5 every now and then

Comment: Bookmark the tag(s) meaning?

Comment: is it meaning Adding to interesting tags

Comment: Means bookmarking the tag directly. Join it as you please for other tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c @sha

Comment: what if i need more than one tag.. like c,c++ and gcc

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37124/limit-on-number-of-tags-in-an-or-query @sha

Answer (score 1):

**`http://code.google.com/p/open-so-frontend/`**

is the application which I really needed. Thanks to the developer who made a simple application using Java Swing :)

Answer (score 0):

Constant Vigilance.

I use the ReloadEvery add-on in Firefox to refresh the Questions page every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up an RSS feed for your favourite tags: see "[Searching and RSS" in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stack-overflow-work-the-official-faq).

Answer (score 0):

I had a little auto-update webservice for a while until I got my servers IP banned... ;)

(Side note: would such a service that fetches new questions on favourite tags be a good or a bad thing? It would mean a lot of requests to the SO server, but a lot more request against my server, as long as there are at least two users connected)