# Streaming questions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto Loading of New Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/auto-loading-of-new-questions)

Why don't stackoverflow have automatic update the homepage just like twitter does.

Answer (score 0):

Because the home page doesn't have to be real-time.

Plus, the home page doesn't show the most recent questions. It shows the questions that you might find interesting and are recent.