# Autoupdate of newest question on SO with AJAX

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto Loading of New Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/auto-loading-of-new-questions)

Wouldn't it be nice if the newest questions flow automatically into the panel like on [twitter.com](http://twitter.com/) to avoid the manual reloading of the page? So you could just watch if something comes up that you're interested in without the manual reload.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow currently gets [3.1k questions per day](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true).  That averages out to over 2 questions per minute, every minute of the day.  That is **way** to much to be able to comfortably follow.  It's a nice-to-have-in-a-fun-sort-of-way, but could you imagine trying to keep up with that?  By the time you're done reading the title of a question in the list, the page would jump as a result of the update.  Aside from the additional tax on the servers, it would have to be done very carefully from the end-user point of view.

Comment: If the panel works smart with my favourite and ignored tags it would totally work.