# Partial rendering on Questions list

Tags: feature-request, questions, ajax

I've noticed that the home page of StackOverflow never reloads unless I refresh my browser.

Are there any plans on changing this so that questions can be loaded into the list via a link such as 'x updated questions. Reload', similar to when new answers have been posted to a question?

Also the time which the questions were last updated never updates without reloading. Therefore a question will display '21s' until refreshed.

Are there any plans to introduce AJAX to sections like this?

Comment: See also: [Auto Loading of New Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/auto-loading-of-new-questions)

Comment: Please *don't* do this. Reloading the questions list would *dramatically* change the questions that appear on that page, given the insane amount of new questions that get posted on a site as large as SO. It would be very difficult for me to find my place. If I want to refresh the list, I'll click "Refresh" in my browser.

Comment: Fair point @Cody Gray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need a push model to do this; at the moment, nothing gets pushed on Stack Exchange except for email notifications.

I have the feeling that it would create a lot of unnecessary traffic, as people leave their computers on the SO home page while they go about their business.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, to be fair I didn't take into account the cost of such a feature.