# Can you make SO home page live?

Tags: feature-request, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto Loading of New Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/auto-loading-of-new-questions)

I want to request SO home page to be live so you can answer quickly if you know the answer to new questions right away, without having to keep refreshing and see.

Being live means,

1. New questions being pushed down from top.
2. Updating n-time ago for questions.
3. Questions score, # of answers and accept-or-not being updated.
4. Updating your reputation score.

I'm sure everyone would like it too.

Comment: Someone could very easily write a UserScript that does this.

Answer (score 9):

Considering how many questions Stack Overflow gets in a day, I'm not sure this would be a good idea.

I also prefer checking if there's anything new at my own pace.