# Why do I get the "confirm navigation" message every time I submit a post on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, navigation, posting, draft

Every time I enter a question on Stack Overflow and hit "post your question", I get this:

[image]

The question still posts without any problems, but the confirmation dialog is really annoying.

**OS:** Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit
**Browser:** Chrome 27.0.1453.93

Comment: In a case of bitter irony, I received the confirmation again when asking this very question.

Comment: Are you using any userscripts?

Comment: Can you recall when this started happening?

Comment: @Antony he's [writing scripts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113566/152859) so the answer is a big Yes. Most likely one of them conflicts with some JS in the page.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The reason I am asking is because I posted (and removed) a userscript on Stack Apps before which had a bug that causes the exact behavior here (it was fixed in a later version, but the script was removed anyway). Given that he is a mod over there, I assume he might have tried it somehow, but I am not so sure.

Comment: @Antony: You, sir, are a genius. I indeed had your UserScript installed.

Comment: @balpha: You may close this as `status-norepro`.

Comment: @NathanOsman I can send you the updated version if you need one. I pulled that off since it wasn't getting enough votes. And recent changes have broken some parts of the script. I have managed to fix that just now.