# Why do I need to manually refresh a question page to watch for responses?

Tags: feature-request, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ajax refreshing for questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/ajax-refreshing-for-questions-and-answers)

I hope it's not asked on meta.stackoverflow

It would be great if Stack Overflow could be like Facebook in that there is no need for any refreshes for the page to see the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would increase the stress on the web servers several times, which would increase the operation costs. I guess Stack Overflow is not there yet to afford that large server farms that Facebook can.

But it would be a nice feature, for sure.