# Questions update in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Auto Loading of New Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/auto-loading-of-new-questions)
>   [Ajax refreshing for questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/ajax-refreshing-for-questions-and-answers)

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before here or if it is appropriate to ask (I searched through stackoverflow and couldn't find one). If it is not relevant to this forum please let me close this thread.

> Why isn't stackoverflow not having new questions that update realtime?
>   I'm talking something like the facebook's sidebar that updates
>   frequently(or whenever somebody comments or likes a page). If
>   something similar to that is provided for new questions then
>   refreshing each time to view new questions could be avoided.

There have been a lot of conversations for related questions in stackoverflow but I seldom found anything for real time update of new questions. Is it a feature that is already available and I am missing or is it not? I am aware that there are a lot of questions that are being asked simultaneously but updating the questions that the user is particularly interested in would be a great feature.

Comment: while(1){ f5(); }

Comment: What's the point of that? SO is Q&A site, not a discussion board or a social networking site, so real time updates are not necessary. The closest you'll get to that is the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto Loading of New Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/auto-loading-of-new-questions), also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/ajax-refreshing-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: What if you are here just to answer and learn things? In that case all I would do is to just refresh and see if any question really interests me or a question for which I could provide a better answer. I am sure a lot of people are here for that.